# How to print a string that contains quotes in python

Tags: python

I want to print quotes in python.
Is it possible to print a `"` in python or any other language? I tried `print("""")`. Here `a` & `b` are useless because it was giving inappropriate grammar error.

```
a = 3
b ="cd"
print("""")
```

Comment: `print('"')` That's an double-quote inside single-quotes. Or `print("\"")` escape the double-quote

Comment: You can escape it: `print("\"")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in single quotes.

```py
print('AAA " AAA " AAA')
# => AAA " AAA " AAA
```

Or escape the quotes:

```py
print("AAA \" \" AAA ")
# => AAA " " AAA
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways:

> **Use single and double quotes together:**
>
> You are allowed to start and end a string literal with single quotes
>   (also known as apostrophes), like 'blah blah'. Then, double quotes can
>   go in between,

```
print ('"quotation marks"')
"quotation marks"
```

> **Escape the double quotes within the string:**
>
> You can put a backslash character followed by a quote (\" or \'). This is called an
>   escape sequence and Python will remove the backslash, and put just the
>   quote in the string.

```
print ("\"quotation marks\"")
"quotation marks"
```

**Use triple-quoted strings:**

```
print (""" "quotation marks" """)
"quotation marks"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print a quote by escaping it with the \ character.

```
print("\"")
```

The \ will cancel the next symbols syntactical meaning an use it as a character.

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(' \' ')  # works with any quotes

print(" \" ")  # works with any quotes

print(' " ')   # only works for opposite quotes.

print(" ' ")   # only works for opposite quotes.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('""""')
```

or

```
print("\"\"\"\"")
```

or

```
print('"'*4)
```