# How Can I Print Something That Has a Lot of Apostrophes?

Tags: python, string

I am wondering how it would be possible to print this out in python:

```
yes2 = "document.querySelector('[ng-controller="inventoryController"]
 [ng-src="https://tr.rbxcdn.com/79a405190ab6aab0429c1eb4f083cfea/150/150/Hat/Png"]
```

because if I do this in python using pyautogui:

```
pyautogui.typewrite("'yes2 = "document.querySelector('[ng-controller="inventoryController"] [ng-src="https://tr.rbxcdn.com/79a405190ab6aab0429c1eb4f083cfea/150/150/Hat/Png"])'")
```

I get a syntax error

Comment: Surround it with triple quotes.

Comment: Alternatively, you could escape each double-quote with the backslash \ by placing the backslash before the " symbol like \" (albeit a much more tedious method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a string that contains quotes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018995/how-to-print-a-string-that-contains-quotes-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Triple quotes.

print('''yes2 = "document.querySelector('[ng-controller="inventoryController"]
[ng-src="https://tr.rbxcdn.com/79a405190ab6aab0429c1eb4f083cfea/150/150/Hat/Png"]''')