# Python - print the quote

Tags: python

How do I get Python to print the following quote, (including the double quotes), in a variable
"Albert Einstein's best quote is "I have no special talent. I am only passionately curious."

The ' after Einstein seems to trigger an invalid syntax error

Comment: As a note for future, you should always include your own code as well, and then print the error message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a string that contains quotes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018995/how-to-print-a-string-that-contains-quotes-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a backslash (`\`) as an escape sequence. Your line of code would look something like this.

```py
string = '"Albert Einstein\'s best quote is "I have no special talent. I am only passionately curious."'
print(string)
```

---

Output:

> "Albert Einstein's best quote is "I have no special talent. I am only
> passionately curious."

Answer (score -1):

**Use a backslash `\` before the first double quote `"` and a backslash before the second double quote `"` to print a string with double quotes.**

Here's my approach to the problem-

Code:

```
s="Albert Einstein's best quote is \"I have no special talent. I am only passionately curious.\"";

print(s);
```

Output:

> Albert Einstein's best quote is "I have no special talent. I am only passionately curious."

Go through this article for a detailed explanation by GeeksforGeeks-
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-printing-string-with-double-quotes/

Comment: The question was to find a way to include the double quotes as well, at the beginning and end of sentence